# What guarantees are provided if one thread mutates an object already in one of the concurrent collections?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

If thread one puts a mutable object A into a concurrent collection, like a ConcurrentSkipListMap, I understand that this is thread-safe in the sense that if thread 2 'get's the object A from the collection, it is guaranteed to be fully visible.

However, if thread one has mutated object A while it is in the collection, does getting it by thread two still provide the same full visibility guarantee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, if thread one has mutated object A while it is in the collection, does getting it by thread two still provide the same full visibility guarantee?

No, definitely not. The concurrency guarantees *only* apply to the collection itself. Once you've fetched the element from the collection, it's *just* a reference in a normal way - so even if there was a memory barrier at the end of the "get" operation, there'd still be the possibility of something like:

```
 Thread 1                   Thread 2

   get
                              get
                              mutate
   read
```

... and after both `get` operations had occurred, the collection is irrelevant.

Concurrent collections should be used for:

- Immutable types which are naturally safe to use from multiple threads
- Types which *are* mutable, but which you never mutate
- Types where you apply explicit synchronization etc to ensure safety